# Turning off "Enter outlining mode when files open" prevents File Compare from working

Tags: visual-studio-2015

If I go to *`Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | Advanced`* and then turn off *`"Enter outlining mode when files open"`*, then I cannot subsequently use *`Source Control | Compare`* to compare files.

If I do so, I only see a blank window where I should see two files side-by-side.

This happens with C# projects and ".cs" files.

Does anyone else see this problem? And if so, does anyone know of a workaround?

[EDIT]

Seems other people have this issue - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00bb6e4e-1e3c-40e4-ba09-479d67e622e2/blank-compare-window-in-vs-2015-rc-for-c-files?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to install [Visual Studio Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) (or later) which fixes the bug.